# why is libpython3.6.so much larger than python2.7 executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python2.7 and python3.6 in my Ubuntu, both installed from apt-get.

I found python2.7 is only 3.4M, but python3.6 approximates 12M, why so big difference?

The following is the command:

```
bash-4.3$ ls -lh `which python2.7`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.4M Nov 13 03:46 /usr/bin/python2.7

bash-4.3$ ls -lh `which python3.6`
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 18K May  5  2018 /usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Seems python3.6 executable uses dynamic linking, so I used  `pamp` to find that .so file :

```
00007fdf14242000    2668 r-x-- 0000000000000000 008:00001 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
00007fdf144dd000    2044 ----- 000000000029b000 008:00001 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
00007fdf146dc000      12 r---- 000000000029a000 008:00001 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
00007fdf146df000     408 rw--- 000000000029d000 008:00001 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

It's libpython3.6m.so.1.0, then I checked its file size:

```
bash-4.3$ ls -lh /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 12M May  5  2018 /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

12M, why so large?

And I'm also confused that libpython3.6m.so.1.0 only occupies (2668k+2044k=)4.7M  in virtual address space, where has the other 7.3M gone?

Thank you.

PS: I also used `pmap` to check the address space of python2.7, no dynamic library of python found, so I think python2.7 is statically linked.

Comment: Is this a curiosity-based question, or do you have an actual problem? (Also, have you tried looking with `objdump`?)

Comment: ...btw, one of these being a vendor-provided build and one is 3rd-party (MacPorts?) makes the comparison potentially quite apples-to-oranges; if the 3rd-party build statically links in libraries that your OS vendor links to dynamically, well, there you are. Different decisions about whether to enable compiler flags for unrolling loops, or whether to build a "fat binary" with code for multiple architectures, can also have a significant impact; there would be fewer confounding factors if you were comparing two MacPorts builds.

Comment: Python2 and Python3 aren't the same thing so they're different. There doesn't seem to be much that can actually be answered in here.

Comment: Not only are they completely different languages, they could have been compiled with wildly different flags and options. Voting to close.

Comment: @Cubic & wim They're hardly different languages. The languages and APIs themselves are about 90% the same. Sure, the string issues are kind of a big deal, but aside from that, when actually writing code, the only other major difference is some new things built in and a couple renames. If you're referring more to under-the-hood stuff, sure, I'll buy that they're significantly different runtimes, but that's a far cry from being "different languages."